# my code taking multiple strings and counting whitespaces

Tags: java, whitespace

So I'm writing a program that takes in three scanner inputs at a time and counts all the whitespaces in the strings before returning the amount totaled. (scanner inputs are predetermined with testcases in JUnit in another class).

This is my code currently, and I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

```
public static int findMostWhitespace (Scanner scn)
{
    String[] array = new String[3];
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        array[i] = scn.nextLine();
    }
    String input = array[0];
    int spaces = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
        if (Character.isWhitespace(input.charAt(i)))
            spaces++;
        }
        String input2 = array[1];
        for (int i = 0; i < input2.length(); i++) {
            if (Character.isWhitespace(input2.charAt(i)))
                spaces++;
        }
        String input3 = array[2];
        for (int i = 0; i < input3.length(); i++) {
            if (Character.isWhitespace(input3.charAt(i)))
                spaces++;
        }
        return spaces;
    }        
}
```

Is there a more efficient way to go about this?

Comment: You could use a `Pattern` and `Matcher` to remove the white-space in every `String`, and return the difference in length.

Comment: And use a `for` loop to iterate through the array when counting the spaces, instead of writing virtually identical code for the individual strings.  You clearly know how.  In fact, you could even integrate the space-counting code right into the same loop that's reading the strings.

Answer (score 1):

Just use replace to replace the whitespaces and count the difference in length

```
//Scanner scn = new Scanner (System.in);
public static int findMostWhitespace (Scanner scn)
  int numOfSpaces = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    String str = scn.nextLine();
    int strlen = str.length();
    numOfSpaces += strlen - str.replaceAll(" ", "").length();
  }

  return numOfSpaces;
}
```

Comment: not sure how I would implement this to take in the strings in my array

Comment: why do you need an array?  In your sample code they go out of scope as soon as the method exits

Comment: well there the test class is as follows:     @Test
    public void testFindMostWhitespace ()
    {
        assertEquals(-1, Loops.findMostWhitespace(new Scanner("")));
        assertEquals(2, Loops.findMostWhitespace(new Scanner("a b c")));
        assertEquals(3, Loops.findMostWhitespace(new Scanner("a bb\na bb\t\t\nxyz")));
    }        essentially i need to take all the strings and output the whitespace of total

Comment: I have made a simple edit to put in into a method, something that would have been more useful for you to try to do and learn along the way.

Answer (score 0):

First, Remove duplicated code.

```
public static int findMostWhitespace (Scanner scn)
    {
        int spaces = 0;
        String input;
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            input = scn.nextLine();
            for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
                if (Character.isWhitespace(input.charAt(i)))
                    spaces++;
            }
        }
        return spaces;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

here's the logic

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

    String s1="hello    world hi";
    System.out.println(s1.length());
    String s2=s1.replaceAll("\\s+","");
    System.out.println(s2.length());
    int count =s1.length()-s2.length();
    System.out.println("White Space "+count);


    }
}
```

it can also count duplicate space by replacing all using `\\s+`
and the output is

```
17
12
White Space 5
```

explanation 
first print statement prints the total length

second print statement print the length after removing space

third difference between them ie total white space